# Update Weld version in Apache jetty

Tags: jetty, weld

I am using Apache Jetty 9.2.10 which uses weld `weld-servlet-2.2.5.Final.jar`.

Is it possible to update weld version to the last release? I did not find a procedure to update jetty modules in its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to decide whether you bundle these implementations in your application or whether you want to use the module system in Jetty.

From your question I would guess it is the module way.
Then it should be very straightforward.

- get `weld-servler.jar` and `weld-servlet-core.jar` in your desired version
- in `${jetty_dir}/lib` create a folder `weld` and put the above jars into it
- in `${jetty_dir}/modules` create `weld.mod` file:

and type in the following:

```
[depend]
jndi
annotations
plus

[lib]
lib/weld/*.jar
```

- as a last step, edit `${jetty_dir}/start.ini` and add a sinle line containing `--module=weld`

Now you should be able to start server and deploy an app using CDI/Weld.

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/KlausBrunner/9349541) to external information about this.